# New to C: whats wrong with my program?

Tags: c

I know my way around ruby pretty well and am teaching myself C starting with a few toy programs. This one is just to calculate the average of a string of numbers I enter as an argument.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char *token;
   int sum = 0;
   int count = 0;
   token = strtok(argv[1],",");
   while (token != NULL)
   {
     count++;
     sum += (int)*token;
     token = strtok(NULL, ",");
   }

 printf("Avg: %d", sum/count);
 printf("\n");
 return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
mike@sleepycat:~/projects/cee$ ./avg 1,1
Avg: 49
```

Which clearly needs some adjustment.

Any improvements and an explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: (int)*token is adding the ASCII value of the single character at the start of the string... (ASCII of '1' is 49) / try atoi(token).

Comment: As everyone has mentioned, you're *casting* rather than *converting* `token`. In C, a cast merely allows the compiler to "reinterpret" a variable's contents in a different context. _The content doesn't change!_ The content of '1' and 49 are the same, where as '1' and 1 are completely different as thus requires a conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line: `sum += (int)*token;`
Casting a **char** to an **int** takes the ASCII value of the **char**.  for 1, this value is 49.

Use the **atoi** function instead:

```
sum += atoi(token);
```

Note **atoi** is found in the `stdlib.h` file, so you'll need to **#include** it as well.

Answer (score 5):

Look for `sscanf` or `atoi` as functions to convert from a string (array of characters) to an integer.

Unlike higher-level languages, C doesn't automatically convert between string and integral/real data types.

Comment: Please be careful with atoi(). It is a hack: if the input doesn't actually look like a number at all, it will just return 0. That leaves you with no way to determine if the input was really "0", or "foo".

Comment: Regarding `atoi()`: the safer `strtol()` will set `errno` for invalid input.

Comment: @chrisaycock is right, `strtol()` (or `strtoul()` for unsigned values) is a better choice and you can use the tail pointer to know where the next character is to convert (and whether the conversion worked at all).

Answer (score 3):

49 is the ASCII value of '1' char.

It should be helpful to you....:D

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the character "1" is 49.  You have to convert the character value to an integer and then average.

Answer (score 3):

In C if you cast a `char` to an `int` you just get the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) value of it.  So, you're averaging the ascii value of the character 1 twice, and getting what you'd expect.

You probably want to use `atoi()`.

EDIT: Note that this is generally true of all typecasts in C.  C doesn't reinterpret values for you, it trusts you to know what exists at a  given location.

Answer (score 3):

> strtok(

Please, please do not use this. Even its own documentation says never to use it. I don't know how you, as a Ruby programmer, found out about its existence, but please forget about it.

> `(int)*token`

This is not even close to doing what you want. There are two fundamental problems:

1) A char* does not "contain" text. It points at text. `token` is of type `char*`; therefore `*token` is of type `char`. That is, a single byte, not a string. Note that I said "byte", not "character", because the name `char` is actually wrong - an understandable oversight on the part of the language designers, because Unicode did not exist back then. Please understand that `char` is fundamentally a **numeric** type. There is **no** real text type in C! Interpreting a sequence of `char` values as text is **just a convention**.

2) Casting in C does not perform any kind of magical conversions.

What your code does is to grab the byte that `token` points at (after the `strtok()` call), and cast that **numeric value** to int. The byte that is rendered with the symbol `1` actually has a value of 49. Again, interpreting a sequence of bytes as text is just a convention, and thus interpreting a byte as a character is just a convention - specifically, here we are using the convention known as ASCII. When you hit the `1` key on your keyboard, and later hit enter to run the program, the chain of events set in motion by the command window actually passed a byte with the value 49 to your program. (In the same way, the comma has a value of 44.)

---

Both of the above problems are solved by using the proper tools to parse the input. Look up `sscanf()`. However, **you don't even want to pass the input to your program this way**, because you can't put any spaces in the input - each "word" on the command line will be passed as a separate entry in the argv[] array.

What you should do, in fact, is **take advantage of that**, by just expecting each entry in argv[] to represent one number. You can again use `sscanf()` to parse each entry, and it will be much easier.

---

Finally:

> printf("Avg: %d", sum/count)

The quotient `sum/count` will not give you a decimal result. Dividing an integer by another integer yields an integer in C, discarding the remainder.

Answer (score 2):

You can't convert a string to an integer via

```
sum += (int)*token;
```

Instead you have to call a function like `atoi()`:

```
sum += atoi (token);
```

Answer (score 1):

when you cast a char (which is what *token is) to int you get its ascii value in C - which is 49... so the average of the chars ascii values is in fact 49. you need to use atoi to get the value of the number represented